# Diverging package lists between APT and KDE Discover

Tags: apt, package-management, kubuntu, 20.04, discover-software-center

When I boot into Kubuntu 20.04, the Discover application launches and shows me a list of available updates. But when I go to the terminal and do an `apt-get update` followed by `apt-get upgrade` these software packages don't appear.

This is a new, stock installation. I haven't even installed git or vim! :)

They all look to be development-related: build-essential, binutils, fakeroot, gcc, etc.

[image: discover]
None of these packages are installed, at least according to apt:

```
$ apt-cache policy binutils
binutils:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.34-6ubuntu1
  Version table:
     2.34-6ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

Why are the lists different? I don't want conflicting installations between APT and Discover...

Comment: Figuring out Discover maybe more difficult than dealing with `apt-get`. Plus, it appears that many KDE users prefer not to use Discover for managing their software. Please run `sudo apt update`. Follow that with `sudo apt full-upgrade`. If you see something you don't like, abort the command and post the entire output here. If it matters, I'll point out that I have all the packages you listed in your image present on my Kubuntu 20.04 as well although they weren't part of the initial install.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of aspects to your question.

## The disparity between what Discover and the terminal show re. updates:

It's *possible* that Discover showed you more updates than the terminal: my answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/524398/61798) may be relevant. But I don't use Discover much at all and so the actual reason for the disparity maybe something else.

*Edit*: Today, 20200520,

- on Kubuntu 20.04, I'm offered the same four packages by Discover and by `sudo apt full-upgrade` (via the terminal): `gir1.2-secret-1 liblirc-client0 libsecret-1-0 libsecret-common`.
- on KDE neon, I'm offered the same thirteen packages.

I'll keep checking future updates to see if there's any divergence.

## The development-related packages:

Nothing specific to Kubuntu here! For whatever reason, these packages are being pushed out to other *buntu flavors as well. Here's output from Lubuntu 20.04:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binutils binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu build-essential dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-9
  gcc gcc-9 libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libasan5
  libatomic1 libbinutils libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcc1-0 libcrypt-dev libctf-nobfd0 libctf0
  libdpkg-perl libfakeroot libfile-fcntllock-perl libgcc-9-dev libitm1 liblsan0 libquadmath0
  libstdc++-9-dev libtsan0 libubsan1 linux-headers-5.4.0-31 linux-headers-5.4.0-31-generic
  linux-image-5.4.0-31-generic linux-libc-dev linux-modules-5.4.0-31-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-31-generic make manpages-dev
```

Note the "NEW" in

> The following NEW packages will be installed:

So, we're getting those packages not by way of updating existing packages.

---

To conclude, you can use either route to keep your system updated and to install new software but I still prefer, and recommend, the terminal.